# actionListener using in Memory Game Client - server application

Tags: java, swing

I'm solving one problem and I've kinda stucked. I'll start with some background.
I'm programing memory game (for example it is something like this http://www.mathsisfun.com/games/memory/index.html). It should be client-server aplication.
client - in java
server - in C

situation is 1 server, N clients

server will have list of games - in each game two players
each game will be separately process in onw process - i use fork

client is java swing form aplication - and represets players
clients and server comunicate only with two methods (resp. functions)

client - void sendMessageToServer(String message), String recieveMessageFromerver()
server - recieveMessage(void *vptr, size_t maxlen, 
       int socketfileDesc) ,int sendMessageToClient(char* msg, int socket)
simply - i just send string messages from server to client, client to server I which are coded actions

Now my problem:
For easier testing client side a made server also in java, and I solve problem only with one game - one server, 2 clients (both in java)
so I have 3 classes
Clilent:
- show the from,
- has info about game,
- has static method CreateAndShowGUI(String serverInsanceHandle) => show - the form, make instance of client
Server:
- just two messages - recieve, send i mentioned before
Test:

```
public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Server server = new Server();
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
                Client.createAndShowGUI(server);
                Client.createAndShowGUI(server);

           }
        });    
    }    
}
```

**HERE:** 

My problem is this: 
for simple testing I have game 4x4 cards this mean 8 pairs
I have array JButton[] buttonsArray = new JButton[16]; on each button is ImageIcon with picture of card, each button have added actionListenner(privateClass)
in privateClass which implements ActionListener is method actionPerformed and there I change set up of the client- I send message to server and server send me back message what I should do in client.
My problem is that I have two clients and one server.
When I make action in client1, it have effect only in client1, but I need somehow let now it to client2.
I can have field of cards what should be viewed on serverside,or I can have field of String messages - with coded changes, but I don't now how to let client2 know that client1 did some action. Comunication must be trough server:
Something like "Hello I'm client1 and I pressed button number 2 so you client2 should ask server for changes" but I' can't do this.
So what can I do?

NOTE: It should be "simulation" of TCP communication, so I'll use tcp sockets - but this is probably not important now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to assume two things about your server:

1. The Server is maintaining the state of the Memory game (IE, which cards are currently flipped over, which client discovered correct pairs of cards, etc.).  I'm going to call this the GameState object.
2. The Server also maintains a unique Socket connection to each Client

It sounds to me like your clients first update their own local GameState, then tell the server to update its GameState.  That said, I'd make the following changes:

1. Each time a client wants to flip a card, or some other action that modifies the GameState, have it send a message to the Server, telling it to update its GameState.
2. Whenever the Server updates its GameState, have it send the entire GameState to all Clients.
3. Design your client to only show GameState that it has received from the server.

This way, your server can control the master GameState and your clients act more like "observers" of that GameState.

Comment: Alternatively to sending the entire game state each time an update is made, you can send the clients the entire game state when they first connect and then just send them messages to update their own game state view. But like Ben said, you want all the actual processing of new game states and player actions to be processed on the Server. This is also a security thing for games to prevent people from cheating by sending the server illegal moves.

Comment: I do it almost same like Ben wrote. I send server message with action and server send back to client message what should client change. 
But I didn't know how send message to all clients - **that was in fact my question**. But something like observer pattern could be my solution. So I add to server side list of observers and if server get message about change (resp action before the change), server notify all observers in the list of observers = send the message with changes to all clienst in the list. Thanks I just forgot that observer pattern exist :D

Comment: Ahhh, missed the part you said about actually sending messages.  It's a bit more complicated than this, but I usually wrap the InputStream and OutputStream of my client-to-server and server-to-client Socket connections inside ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream instances.  Then, so long as your GameState object (or whatever message object you choose to implement) implements Serializable, you can write those objects directly across the socket to the far side.  Kinda cool :)

Comment: I thing the ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream is not possible to use there, cause server will be in C and C couldn't work with that (I'm not sure if it's 100% true, some people said me that is not possible) it's ther reason why I use buffered reader. I must use something what is not dependent on programming language..